# Git pull on remote server using jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I have this for the git checkout stage and it works fine

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
     branches: [[name: "*/master" ]],
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
     extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]],
     submoduleCfg: [],
     userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: env.GIT_CREDS, url: env.GIT_REPO]]
         ])
```

I am trying to configure a jenkins job (using jenkins pipeline) to do a *git pull* on a remote server using **sshagent**
I need to use the **GIT_CREDS** defined in the pipeline for git pull on remote server
Need something like:

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@$Ip 'git pull'"
```

using *GIT_CREDS* and *GIT_REPO* env variables

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Just use git

```
git(
    url: 'git@git.com:YourGitRepo.git',
    credentialsId: '5ef933f28-bdb2-0563-bfc7-b460490262735', // found here http://jenkinsURL:8080/credentials/
    branch: 'master'
    )
```

Internally it use ssh.
Hope it helps :)